# Kellerman Object Comparison for lists and collections

Tags: c#, list, object, properties, compare

I am attempting to use the Kellerman object comparison code to report all of the changes properties on an object. I am particularly interested in which properties have been changed from default. To this end, I am having Kellerman compare the object that has been modified to a newly created instance of this object. The problem is that Kellerman doesn't handle the case when one object's list is empty and the other is populated. It only reports the difference in the count of the lists and how those differ. Ideally, it goes object by object and property by property in the list and reports the properties that have changed in the object that does have data within it. Does anyone know how to configure Kellerman to do this? Is there another library that better suites what I am looking for?

```
Object 1    Object 2
-list1      -list1(empty)
 -elem1
  -prop1
  -prop2      
 -elem2
  -prop1

Object 1                     Object 2
list1.count = 2              Object 2 list1.count = 0
list1.elem1.prop1 = "blah"  (Object 2 does not have corresponding property) 
list1.elem1.prop2 = "blah"  (Object 2 does not have corresponding property)
list1.elem2.prop1 = "blah"  (Object 2 does not have corresponding property)
```

Comment: Why do you need Kellermann if one list is empty? In that case everything has changed and you can state that without any library

Comment: I am using Kellerman in this case to state _which_ properties have changed. Not all properties are changed everytime. This is what I want to track by comparing against the empty object. Conceptually, I want a library I can ask "What did I change to my object since I constructed it?"

Comment: Oh well you can see it right there: You added two elements

Comment: What is written above is what I want Kellerman (or any library) to report, not what it currently reports.